# Wordpress, show or hide header on posts by post categories

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hi i have an wp website and i'm using **avada theme**. I want to hide header according to its category. For example if posts category is "A" then i dont want to show header on the top automatically. I know i can manually adjust that in the post settings on every posts, or set a layout and select that layout on the below but i dont want to deal that every time.

So i try a if statement in the **archives.php**.
its something like this:

```
<?php if(has_category( 'A' )) : ?>    //i also try in_category and on_category

<?php  else: ?>
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but its probably for category page itself but not for posts.

Can anybody help with that?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**hi you can go with following links and follow the given solution it may worked..**

here it show that how to hide specific c***ategorize header post*** ...

https://wpquestions.com/Remove_header_or_styling_from_specific_category_of_posts/11505